# Why does TypeScript have a structual typing system?

Tags: typescript, structural-typing

I thought that object oriented programming was created because it relates to the human way of thinking, but structural typing does not seem to fit this assumption.

Consider for example two classes with the same structure:

```
class Robot {
  name: string
}

class Human {
  name: string
}
```

I could use references of class Robot to point to Human instances or viceversa but, of course,  if you ask a human, Robot and Human are not the same thing.

When I change the structure of one of these classes I have also to change the Robot references wherever they point to a Human instance.

Comment: `Why` is a bit to opinion based for SO I think, but the technical reason I believe to be JS compatibility. TS tries to allow everything JS allows (or everything that is safe)  but in a type-safe way. You can't do that with nominal typing this is why we got structural typing :)

Comment: Even though you can duck type your two objects and find out that currently they behave similar, there is no contract enforcing that they will continue to behave similar. Hence you should never use references directly against those concrete classes (unless that class NEEDS that one class instances). The OOP would be to have a common interface and both classes would implement this. (In this case the interface might be called `Entity` and the shared method would be `getName`.)

Comment: It would be better to ask, what benefits a structural typing has over nominal typing. In my opinion this is one of the most exciting features of this language and why it is so versatile.